# Testing the contents of a text field against several different strings

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa

I am having trouble figuring out how to check if a text field contains any of a few different strings. This is what I have, but it does not work:

```
- (IBAction)Submit:(id)sender { 

    if ([Input.text isEqualToString:@"axe"/"apple"/"angry"])
        Output.text = @"CORRECT";
    else Output.text = @"INCORRECT";
```

If the input text field contains "axe", "apple", or "angry" then the Output Label should display "CORRECT", otherwise it should display "INCORRECT".

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want from what you said at the end of the question:

> If the input text field = axe, apple or angry then the Output Label = correct but if not output label = Incorrect.

So this is the code:

```
if([Input.text isEqualToString:@"axe"] || [Input.text isEqualToString:@"apple"] || [Input.text isEqualToString:@"angry"]) {

    Output.text = @"CORRECT";
}
else {
    Output.text = @"INCORRECT";
}
```

You were looking for the "or" operator, which is "||".

You also said:

> I am having trouble finding out if there is a way to compile a number of words into the same string.

To do that, you can try this:

```
NSString *str1 = @"axe";
NSString *str2 = @"apple";
NSString *str3 = @"angry";
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", str1, str2, str3];
```

Comment: By the way, you are missing some ['s in your if statement and a " in the CORRECT string creation....

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a slightly different approach:

```
// Create an array with all of the acceptable words:
NSArray *correctWords = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"axe", 
                                                  @"apple", 
                                                  @"angry", nil];

// Check to see if the input text matches one of the correct words 
// (stored in the array), and set the Output text:
if ([correctWords containsObject:Input.text]) {
    Output.text = @"CORRECT";
} else {
    Output.text = @"INCORRECT";
}
```